# Select random array variable name in bash

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

_0=("Mami"  "Bebe"  "Princesa"  "Mami")
_1=("Yo quiero " "Yo puedo "  "Yo vengo a " "Voy a ")
_2=("Encenderte"  "Amarte"  "Ligar"  "Jugar")
_3=("Suave"  "Lento"  "Rapido"  "Fuerte")
_4=("Hasta que salga el sol " "Toda la noche "  "Hasta el amanecer "  "Todo el dia ")
_5=("Sin anestecia " "Sin compromiso " "Feis to feis " "Sin Miedo ")

b=$(( $RANDOM % 6 ))

echo _$b[@]
```

I want to select randomly one array and print its value.

Comment: Why not use a `case` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60584/how-to-use-a-variable-as-part-of-an-array-name). Adapting it to your script, the last two lines become:

```
b=_$(( $RANDOM % 6 ))[@]
echo ${!b}
```

Comment: Thanks Vasan, It was what I really wanted

Comment: Mr vasan i use too: c=$(( $RANDOM % 4 ))
b=_$(( $RANDOM % 6 ))[c]
echo ${!b}